# Remove Netbeans Auto Generated Code After Double-Clicking an Object in Design Tab

Tags: java, events, user-interface, object, netbeans

So Im using Netbeans and the Design tab, placing labels, textboxes, etc.  Great, however when you double-click on say a label it autogenerated this code:

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Now I didn't want it to do that, but when I highlight and attempt to delete it - Netbeans does not allow me to do so.  How do I go about removing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Design mode you select the particular object and click Events under Properties and remove the event from the event property

Comment: How about in a more general case?  For example i created  JPanel, realized i am just going to extend from some other class, and no longer need the initComponents method.  This is not attached to an event; what do I do to convince netbeans that this is no longer needed?

Comment: @BrianSweeney Just remove the GUI-builder's JPanel, and *"extend from some other class"* manually (not sure if you mean using a different element; but not a good idea to go around making use of Frankenstein instances anyways; the builder expects to use the builder's panel with the builder's code...If you're going to actually extend JPanel or use a JPanel-like instance extending from some other class, you should create those manually).

Answer (score 5):

To answer Brian's question on the more general case:

If you have auto-generated variables that are hiding in the Design mode, and you cannot select and remove them, you can usually delete them with the following steps(in NetBeans7.4):

1. Go in the Design mode to the top window `menu -> Windows -> Navigator`. You will see Group **"Navigator"** popped up on the left (usually).
2. Now you can delete unwanted variables (or edit them) with the **right click** menu.

Answer (score 1):

### Easiest Solution

Close net beans IDE and open the source file you need to change in a text editor available in your system. then you can remove (also can edit) your line of code.Then save the changes. After that open netbeans you can see the changes in netbeans.

hope helpfull for you!!